# php curl help with google url shortner api

Tags: php, json, curl

Im trying to shorten a url using ggole api's.Here is my php code .It gives a blank page when i load

```
<?php
    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'GoogleApiKey');
    define('GOOGLE_ENDPOINT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1');

    function shortenUrl($longUrl)
    {
        // initialize the cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init(
            sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', GOOGLE_ENDPOINT, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        );

        // tell cURL to return the data rather than outputting it
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // create the data to be encoded into JSON
        $requestData = array(
            'longUrl' => $longUrl
        );

        // change the request type to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // set the form content type for JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

        // set the post body to encoded JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));

        // perform the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // decode and return the JSON response
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) {  
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $response = shortenUrl('$url');

    echo sprintf(
        $response['longUrl'],
        $response['id']
     );
 }
?>
```

My html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD =" " ACTION = "shortner.php">

<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="Enter a url to shorten" name="url">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Shorten">

</FORM>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: `shortenUrl('$url');` needs to use double quotes (or none at all).

Comment: Read my answer again, I just edit it now. I think I solve all your problem. I can really test cause I don't have any api key. But It's seems to work.

Comment: Thanks simon i got it.hhey im getting output but when i enter a url from my html file it goes and fetches the shortened url .How do i capture that shortned url and display it in a html page.NOt as php ouput

Comment: How do i output it to my html file where the input was given and display the shortened url below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's coming form your html. You didn't put the form methode, so it send data by get.

And you show something only if you have post.

Try to do in the form method="post"

---

Edit

Bobby the main problem is that you don't have one problem but several in this code.
First if you don't do

```
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="shortner.php">
```

the `if (isset($_POST['url']))` will never return true, because the variable send by the form will be GET (or do a `if (isset($_GET['url']))`).

Secondly you call the function with `{ $response = shortenUrl('$url'); }.` Here you're not sending the url value but the string '$url'. So your variable $longUrl is always '$url'.

Thirdly you don't use sprintf like you should.

```
echo sprintf(
        $response['longUrl'],
        $response['id']
     );
```

Sprintf need to take a string format:

```
echo sprintf("%s %s" // for example
    $response['longUrl'],
    $response['id']
 );
```

But do you know that you can do directly

```
echo $response['longUrl'] . ' ' . $response['id'];
```

You can concatenate string directly with . in php

Comment: OP's form submission has nothing to do with the problem - on his form handler he's submitting the request to google's shorterner via POST anyways.

Comment: Of course it does when he does if (isset($_POST['url'])) { $response = shortenUrl('$url'); }, So when you click on the form button, you NEVER call the shortnUrl() function. You can do whatever you want after, if the code is never call... Btw bobby, when stuff are not working like that you should but debug everywhere, to see exactly what part of you code are execute.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found a solution to your problem. Since you are connecting to a URL that uses SSL, you will need to add some extra parameters to your code for CURL. Try the following instead:

```
<?php
    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'GoogleApiKey');
    define('GOOGLE_ENDPOINT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1');

    function shortenUrl($longUrl)
    {
        // initialize the cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init(
            sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', GOOGLE_ENDPOINT, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        );

        // tell cURL to return the data rather than outputting it
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // create the data to be encoded into JSON
        $requestData = array(
            'longUrl' => $longUrl
        );

        // change the request type to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // set the form content type for JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

        // set the post body to encoded JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));

        // extra parameters for working with SSL URL's; eypeon (stackoverflow)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        // perform the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // decode and return the JSON response
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) {  
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $response = shortenUrl('$url');

    echo sprintf(
        $response['longUrl'],
        $response['id']
     );
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl_exec()` returns boolean false if something didn't go right with the request. You're not testing for that and assuming it worked. Change your code to:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Curl error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
```

As well, you need to specify CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - by default curl will write anything it receives to the PHP output. With this option set, it'll return the transfer to your $result variable, instead of writing it out.

Comment: `json_decode()` also returns NULL if the json data can't be decoded, so you might want to check for that case as well. THere could be garbage in the google response you have to filter out, or google's returning a plaintext (non-json) response of some sort. Might want to log the `$result` somewhere before trying to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option in your code

```
function shortenUrl($longUrl)
    {
        // initialize the cURL connection
        $ch = curl_init(
            sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', GOOGLE_ENDPOINT, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
        );

        // tell cURL to return the data rather than outputting it
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // create the data to be encoded into JSON
        $requestData = array(
            'longUrl' => $longUrl
        );

        // change the request type to POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        // set the form content type for JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));


        // set the post body to encoded JSON data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestData));


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


        // perform the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // decode and return the JSON response
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) {  
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $response = shortenUrl('$url');

    echo sprintf(
        $response['longUrl'],
        $response['id']
     );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Create cURL
$apiURL = https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=gfskdgsd
$ch = curl_init();
// If we're shortening a URL...
if($shorten) {
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(array("longUrl"=>$url)));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: application/json"));
}
else {
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->apiURL.'&shortUrl='.$url);
}
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
// Execute the post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close the connection
curl_close($ch);
// Return the result
return json_decode($result,true);
```